# C language Changing For Loop to While loop

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, while-loop

How to make **for loop** to **while loop** 
Is it possible to change **for loop** in *array* to **while loop**?

> change

```
for(i = 0; i < 12; ++i) //for loop for selecting only positive
    {
        if(a[i] > 0) printf("%d ", a[i]); //display positive only using if statement
    }
```

```
to
```

```
int i = 0, a[12];
    while(i < 12)
    {
        if(a[i] > 0)
        {
            printf("%d ", a[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }
```

but it doesn't display the positive same as the negative if changed..

Comment: "_but changing to while loop makes error in the sca_" Show what you tried to change it to, and quote that mysterious error in full.

Answer (score 2):

```
int i;
for(i=0; i < count; i++)
{
    // Work item here
}
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
int i=0;
while (i < count)
{
    // Work item here
    i++;
}
```

Comment: The `continue` statement disagrees :P

Comment: I'm not using `continue` in my code, and neither is the OP.  But sure.

Comment: Yes, I know, but they are not identical (as you stated)  due to this detail.

Comment: I rephrased.  It's functionally equivalent code; there's no `continue` statement in it.

Comment: Yeah, I was just nitpicking :)

Comment: `printf("\nPositive numbers: ");
    while(i < 12)
    {
        if(a[i] > 0)
        {
            printf("%d ", a[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }`

what's the problem..